# Regex to tell if a string contains a linux file path or if a linux file path as part of a string

Tags: regex, linux, string

I am writing a regular expression that will be used to see if a string contains a file path for a linux system as the whole string or a file path for a linux system as only part of the string. So basically when a file path is the whole string I want a match, but when the file path is just part of the string I don't want a match. For example I would want the following string to tell me there is a match

`/home/user/Documents/foo.log`

and this string not be a match

`/home/user/Documents/foo.log was written`

as well as this string not be a match

`the file /home/user/Documents/foo.log was written`

The only thing I have been able to come up with so far is this,

`^(\/*)`

Which only says ok you have a slash followed by a character but am not sure what else to use to get the regular expression to work as I would like it to. Does anyone have any input on how to expand upon my regular expression to get it to match what I am looking to do?

**EDIT**

Spaces are not part of allowed file names as part of the naming convention. Yes a user could put a space since it is a linux system, however that would then be a user error.

Comment: Any string is a potentially valid Linux file path. What exactly do you want to check?

Comment: `/home/user/Documents/foo.log was written` is a valid linux path name as a whole.

Comment: That it is not part of a string. Since the program will be either transmuting log messages sent to the program or reading from files to transmit log messages. So I want a way to decipher that it wants me to a read a file and that the file name is just not part of a log message

Comment: @n.m. sorry read comment above

Comment: That's strange as a linux valid path is whatever string you imagine with all possible characters except `\0`.  Something like `[^\0]*` will work.  If you don't want to allow spaces in filenames, that would be ok, but linux does accept filenames with spaces, control characters, etc.  The only invalid character for a file name is the NUL character (used for string termination)  Even if you try to disallow sequences of `/` together (as in `//file//a//b`) linux does accept them, compacting the `/` groups into one slash character.  So that file paths are valid also.

Comment: What impides to name a directory `the file ` or to name a file `foo.log was written` in linux???

Comment: The filename conventions might be stated.  As you are reading the file by lines, do I must suppose you won't accept newlines as part of a filename.  Linux accepts newlines in the middle of a filename, as any other control character (except `\0').

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Regex for full Linux filesystem paths can be:

```
^(/[^/ ]*)+/?$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eQ7aV6/2)

Comment: Just added that as part of the naming convention a file should never be added with a space in the name.

Comment: Nope.  slash characters are allowed (even in groups) and spaces, controls, etc.  The only unallowed char is `\0`. So the valid regex would be `[^\0]*`.

Comment: @anubhava, and what about control characters? and what about utf-8 sequences? suppose somebody wants to call his files `****attention_file****.txt` (will be the asterisk admitted? a backslash? a question mark?)  A naming conventio is just that, not an enforcement.  If your user begins a filename with a dot, the convention says that it will not be listed by **ls(1)** (but you'll see it in a readdir(2) system call either)  If the convention says not to accept spaces, then, a correct regexp would be `[^ \0]*

Comment: @anubhava, why are you accepting multiline in your regexp demo.  Are you accepting (you do) `\n` in your filenames (linux accepts them)??? But you have only ***one match*** in your example demo, as you have two lines that match **as only one filename**.  Is this another convention?

Answer (score 4):

The only linux (and unix) not allowed character in a file path is the ascii nul character `\0`  (it's not allowed as it is used as a string terminator ---in this case a path name terminator--- in the **open(2)** system call, so you can have always only one, at the end, not counting as a file character).  Old unices disallowed the grouping of several `/` slash characters together, so the right regexp would be `(\/?[^\0/])+|\/` (a sequence of an optional slash character followed by a non nul and non slash character, or the `/` entry alone ---indicating the root directory)  That allows all the characters but the ascii nul, and doesn't allow two slashes to appear together.  Recent implementations allow grouping of slashes (collapsing them into one) so the valid path regexp would be `[^\0]+`.

But this matches all the input you have exposed (even, it will match all the input as one file path, as `\n` characters are allowed as part of a filename), so you'll have to be more precise in your question to expose what you want and what you don't want to accept.  `"foo.log was written"` and `"the file "` (with that final space) are valid filenames in linux (and in unix).  what about other control characters? What about escape sequences, wildcar characters (like `*` or `?`), etc?

Comment: Thankyou for the negative votes, to whom could have done, without any explanation...  some kind of too constructive way of helping people.

Comment: +1'd it.  The down-voters are probably the same ones that make horribly dangerous unfounded assumptions while writing software which makes life difficult for the rest of us.

Answer (score 1):

`(/)+[a-zA-Z0-9\\-_/ ]*(.log)`

or

`(/)+[a-zA-Z0-9\\-_/ ]*(.cpp)` for to match c++ file path in string.
It may help

Answer (score 0):

For an absolute file path :

```
^(\/[\w^ ]+)+\/?([\w.])+[^.]$
```

For an absolute folder path :

```
^(\/[\w^ ]+)+\/?$
```